# Search using two criterias and copy row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm extremely new to VBA, got stuck for a month with this problem and really need your help please

I start a new excel file every month, and I need to search for specific date intervals (1-10, 11-20, 21-31) for a text in a list then copy the row from sheet 1 to sheet 3. Date format is dd.mm.yyyy and in column F. The text i search is in column B. I managed to make the search for each item in the list and every date but it got ridiculous because I heave around 30 items in my list and 31 days in a month , and some items change every month.

1   TOM     xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  02.03.2016  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx

2   MARY    xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  14.03.2016  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx

3   TOM     xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  20.03.2016  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx

4   ANNA    xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  01.03.2016  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx

5   EMMA    xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  02.03.2016  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx

6   JUSTIN  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  04.03.2016  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx

So if I select dates from 1-10 and my list is TOM, MARY, EMMA

1   TOM     xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  02.03.2016  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx

2   EMMA    xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  02.03.2016  xxxxxx  xxxxxx  xxxxxx

This is what I've managed to do so far, it only searches for the first criteria, the list of names, I just don't know how to make it search to comply also with the dates

```
Sub Names()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long, Names, Day, l As Long
Dim k As Long
k = 13
Dim tocopy As Integer
Sheets(2).Range("A13:R250").Clear
Names= Array("TOM", "MARY", "EMMA")
Day = Array("01.03.2016", "02.03.2016", "03.03.2016", "04.03.2016", "05.03.2016", "06.03.2016", "07.03.2016", "08.03.2016", "09.03.2016", "10.03.2016")
  LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 1 To LR
    With Range("B" & i)
    For j = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
      If .Value Like "*" & Names(j) & "*" Then
        tocopy = 1
        Exit For
      End If
    Next j
    End With
    If tocopy = 1 Then
      Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(3).Rows(k)
      k = k + 1
    End If
    tocopy = 0
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Rule number 1: Format your code! We cannot read it like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim namesArray As Variant, daysInterval As Variant
Dim dataRng As Range
Dim sourceSht As Worksheet, destSheet As Worksheet

namesArray = Array("TOM", "MARY", "EMMA") '<== here set the names to search for
daysInterval = Array(11, 20) '<== here set the days interval

Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("source") '<== here set the name of the worksheet with data to filter
Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("destination") '<== here set the name of the worksheet where to paste filtered data into

Set dataRng = sourceSht.Range("A13:R250") ' here set range with data to be filtered with names and days. it MUST include headers row

With dataRng
    With .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1)
        .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(ISTEXT(RC6),value(LEFT(RC6,2)),"""")"
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=namesArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=.Columns.Count, Criteria1:=">=" & daysInterval(0) & "", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & daysInterval(1) & ""
    End With
    With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=destSheet.Rows(13)
    End With
    .AutoFilter
    .Columns(.Columns.Count + 1).Clear
End With

End Sub
```

with following key notes

- take care to properly set where you find comments "`'<== here set...`"
- the code uses the first column at the left of `dataRng` as a "helper" one. so no relevant data must be in the column since they'll be overwritten

Comment: i have tried, it's not doing anything, i have at least 5 rows that comply the criteria but nothing is copied. I didn't get any errors, and I have set the arrays. The names are in column B and the dates in column F, I have set the range from the header A12:r250.

Comment: Did you get through?

Comment: No, it just doesn't do nothing and I really don't understand why :(

Comment: I tested code and retested it with data as per last your comment (data in A12:R250, names in B and dates in F). so there must be something else in your data structure which "interfere": either you post a file or step through code and watch what's happening, querying variables in the immediate window or hovering over them with the mouse. but firstly you can tell me how've you set `namesArray`, `daysInterval`, `sourceSht` and `destinationSht`